# Transaction on a redis sorted set doesn't appear atomic

Tags: python, redis, transactions, python-multithreading, sortedset

I'm encountering some strange behavior in a pipelined/transaction in Redis that makes me question that the code is actually being executed in a transaction:

```
class RedisThread:

    KEY = "threading_test"

    def __init__(self, id:int):
        self._redis = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
        self._id    = id
        self._redis.delete(self.KEY)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = []
        for i in range(3):
            # Transaction
            pipe = self._redis.pipeline(transaction=True)

            # ZADD current time as score
            pipe.zadd(self.KEY, {f"{self._id}-{i}": time.time()})

            # ZRANK
            pipe.zrank(self.KEY, f"{self._id}-{i}")

            # Commit and get result of ZRANK
            results.append(str(pipe.execute()[1]))

        print(", ".join(results))


    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=RedisThread(1)),
        threading.Thread(target=RedisThread(2)),
        threading.Thread(target=RedisThread(3)),
        threading.Thread(target=RedisThread(4)),
        threading.Thread(target=RedisThread(5)),
    ]

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

When I run this code, this is the result:

```
1, 5, 9
3, 6, 10
0, 3, 13
4, 11, 12
1, 4, 13
```

Notice that there are duplicate values between threads. Since I'm doing a ZRANK, and the values I'm adding (via ZADD) to the set are time based (and thus always increasing in values), I should not be seeing any duplicates, yet there are duplicates...

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I think the issue is my use of `time()` as score, there's a race condition between the time I execute `time()` and when I commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis transaction is atomic. The problem is that you use `time()` as score.

Since the programs runs fast, so `time()` might return the same result for multiple calls. In other words, you are setting members in sorted set with the same score.

If members have the same score, they are sorted by lexicographical order.

Now, let's see why you got duplicate values:

```
thread1: ZADD key same-time 1-0
thread1: ZRANK key 1-0 ----------> 0

thread2: ZADD key same-time 2-0
thread2: ZRANK key 2-0 ----------> 1

thread1: ZADD key same-time 1-1
thread1: ZRANK key 1-1 ----------> 1
```

The second transaction of thread1 executed after the first transaction of thread2, and `1-1` is less than `2-0` in lexicographical order. So when the second transaction of thread1 executed, `1-1` will be inserted before `2-0`, and that's why they both get the rank: `1`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my conclusion as well. I'm assuming there's no way to do this better, right? I'm attempting to make a semaphore in redis (that can be called by different processes).

Comment: How about use a monotonically increasing counter as score, so that each member in sorted set has a unique score. You can use the `INCR` command a get a counter, and then set the counter as score with the ZADD command. With this solution, you won't get duplicate values.

Comment: I'm trying to find documentation on how to use the value from one key as the score for a ZADD. What would that look like?

Comment: You need to run the INCR command first, and use the return value as the score to call ZADD. Or, you can wrap the logic into a Lua script.

Comment: If I run the INCR first, capture the value, then start a transaction to save it via ZADD, wouldn't that suffer from the same race condition as using time?

Comment: The return value of INCR command is unique, and monotonically increasing. So you can use it as the score of sorted set to make sure that each member in the set has a unique score. In order to ensure that the operation is atomic, you can wrap these two commands into a Lua script. And there will be no race condition.

Comment: I think the lua script is the only safe way to do it, since there's no way to do this atomically outside of redis. If I access INCR via app, then put that value back into redis, I lose that atomicity.